# Android(Kotlin) Material Design Date Range Picker How to set Minimum and Maximum dates properly?

Tags: kotlin, date, time

I have a Date Range Picker(Material Design) and I want to disable previous dates(so minimum date will be current day), and maximum date will be 6 months later. I tried something like this:

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val constraintsBuilderRange = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    val dateValidatorMin: CalendarConstraints.DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(calendar.timeInMillis)
    val dateValidatorMax: CalendarConstraints.DateValidator = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(calendar.timeInMillis+100000000)

    val listValidators = ArrayList<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator>()
    listValidators.add(dateValidatorMin)
    listValidators.add(dateValidatorMax)
    val validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators)
    constraintsBuilderRange.setValidator(validators)


    val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
        .setTitleText("Select range")
        .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilderRange.build())
        .build()

    datePicker.show(
        this.requireFragmentManager(),"date_range_picker"
    )
```

This worked but I randomly give 100000000 to `dateValidatorMax`. So how can I achieve 6 months later in milliseconds? And how can I get 1 day before currentDate in `dateValidatorMin`?

Comment: There is 3,600,000 milliseconds in an hour. So for 6 months that is 15,768,017,280 (over 15 billion milliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem thanks to Kotlin, there is a really easy method:

```
val dateValidatorMin: CalendarConstraints.DateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(calendar.timeInMillis - 1.days.toLong(
        DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))
val dateValidatorMax: CalendarConstraints.DateValidator = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(calendar.timeInMillis+ 180.days.toLong(
        DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I needed only dates in the range from the previous day to 45 days behind the current date to be enabled. That is, today, January 18th, the calendar would only be enabled from 12-05-2022 to 01-17-2023.

I did it like this:

```
val dateValidatorMin: DateValidator =
    DateValidatorPointForward.from(
        Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - 45.days.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))

val dateValidatorMax: DateValidator =
    DateValidatorPointBackward.before(
        Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis - 1.days.toLong(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    
val dateValidator: DateValidator = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listOf(dateValidatorMin, dateValidatorMax))

val constraints: CalendarConstraints =
    CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(dateValidator)
        .build()

val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    .setCalendarConstraints(constraints)
    .setTitleText(getString(R.string.label_select_date_range))

val picker = builder.build()
```

And the result was like this:

[image: image showing the range of days enabled]

Hope this helps.